# SDL Tridion content publishing against old versions of templates

Tags: tridion

My content is publishing against earlier or older versions of my uploaded (c# dll) template building blocks.

- When viewing the code in Template Builder - everything is great.
- When previewing / publishing the latest version of the code is not picked up.

Is the uploaded DLL cached somewhere?

I'm using SDL Tridion 2001 SP1 HR 1

Comment: Is your template checked-out? Has it been localized? Does it happen on a single server or multiple server setup?

Comment: nothing is checked out, this is happening on a single cm server.

Comment: Did you restart the publisher on all machines? If any caching is going on, it will be in that module.

Comment: Re: checked-out templates, since 2011 or maybe earlier we could preview template changes against minor versions without checking in and saving a major version. With R5.3 we had to Save & Close to see even preview template changes. So now you might occasionally see everything "fine" in Template Builder or Preview, but actually publishing won't show the changes until we check in the template.

Answer (score 5):

Yes - the publisher caches the assemblies. To investigate the problem, I'd suggest editing 
`C:\Program Files (x86)\Tridion\bin\TcmPublisher.exe.config` to add a logging output file and see if you can get any more information that way.

As Frank says, restarting the publisher should solve the problem.

Comment: Indeed restarting the publisher service did the trick.  Thanks puf dom nuno :)